# Apache Commons Text: Random String for special characters java

Tags: java, random, java-8, apache-commons

I'm using apache `commons-text:RandomStringGenerator` for generating a random `String` like so:

```
//Utilities
private static RandomStringGenerator generator(int minimumCodePoint, int maximumCodePoint, CharacterPredicates... predicates) {
    return new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
            .withinRange(minimumCodePoint, maximumCodePoint)
            .filteredBy(predicates)
            .build();
}

public static String randStringAlpha(int length) {
    return generator('A', 'z', CharacterPredicates.LETTERS).generate(length);
}

public static String randStringAlphaNum(int length) {
    return generator('1', 'z', CharacterPredicates.LETTERS, CharacterPredicates.DIGITS).generate(length);
}

//Generation
private void foo() {
    String alpha = randStringAlpha(255);
    String num = randStringAlphaNum(255);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to use the same library to generate to following:

A - special characters (could be limited to keyboard special characters)

B - alpha + A

C - num + A

D - alpha + num + A

I already checked the `CharacterPredicates enum` but it only has `LETTERS` and `DIGITS` for filtering. Any help would be really appreciated!

## EDIT:===============================================

I decided to shelf my current solution in favor of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49937398/2285470) answer.
To clarify the scope of 'special characters' I was actually looking for this subset: 
[image]

Snippet for case A:

```
public static CharSequence asciiSpecial() {
    return asciiCharacters().toString().replaceAll("(\\d|[A-z])","");
}
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from writing your own `CharacterPredicate` implementation? Apache Commons Text is **open source**, so you have access to the source code of `CharacterPredicates`, allowing to to see how the predefined `CharacterPredicate` implementations are done, so it should be *easy* to write your own in a similar fashion. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ → http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your category “special characters” is quiet fuzzy. As long as you stay with the ASCII range, all characters are either letter, digit or “special”, but can be entered with an ordinary keyboard. In other words, you don’t need to specify a filter at all for that. On the other hand, when you leave the ASCII range, there is a variety of character categories you would have to care of (e.g. you don’t want to insert random combining characters at arbitrary points), further, there is no general test whether a character can be entered with a keyboard (as there is no general keyboard)…

But note that your code trying to use that library is already bigger than code doing the actual work would be. E.g. to get a random letter string, you could use

```
public static String randStringAlpha(int size) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints('A', 'z'+1)
        .filter(Character::isLetter)
        .limit(size)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

or the likely more efficient variant

```
public static String randStringAlpha(int size) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(size, 'A', 'Z'+1)
        .map(c -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()? c: Character.toLowerCase(c))
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

without any 3rd party library.

Likewise, you could generalize the task using

```
public static String randomString(int size, CharSequence validChars) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(size, 0, validChars.length())
        .map(validChars::charAt)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
public static String randomString(int minSizeIncl, int maxSizeIncl, CharSequence valid) {
    return randomString(
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minSizeIncl, maxSizeIncl), valid);
}
public static CharSequence asciiLetters() {
    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.rangeClosed('A','Z'), IntStream.rangeClosed('a','z'))
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,StringBuilder::append);
}
public static CharSequence asciiLetterOrDigit() {
    return IntStream.concat(asciiLetters().chars(),IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '9'))
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,StringBuilder::append);
}
public static CharSequence asciiCharacters() {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed('!', '~')
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,StringBuilder::append);
}
```

Which you can use by combining two methods, e.g.
`RandomString.randomString(10, asciiLetters())`,
`RandomString.randomString(10, asciiLetterOrDigit())`, or
`RandomString.randomString(10, asciiCharacters())`, resp. their variable-size counterparts like `RandomString.randomString(10, 20, asciiCharacters())`.

The `CharSequence`s can be reused between multiple string generation calls, would be similar to building a `RandomStringGenerator` and using it multiple times.

Comment: Simple and easy to modify! Thanks for pointing out fuzzy parts in my question. Your answer was on-point nonetheless. I'll be modifying the question to address your points and to provide an answer to case A -- hope it would help others too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your argument type in method `generator` from `CharacterPredicates` to `CharacterPredicate` and write your custom `CharacterPredicate` like:

```
private static RandomStringGenerator generator(int minimumCodePoint, int maximumCodePoint, CharacterPredicate... predicates) {
    return new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
            .withinRange(minimumCodePoint, maximumCodePoint)
            .filteredBy(predicates)
            .build();
}

public static String randSomething(int length) {
    return generator('1', 'z', new CharacterPredicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(int i) {
            return true; // Write your logic here
        }
    }).generate(length);
}
```

Comment: Even simpler with a lambda expression.